# Filter date from to ng-table AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, ngtable, angularjs-ng-table

I have problem with custom filtering in ng-table (date from - to).
Here's my plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/g1t4pludTTIAJYKTToCK?p=preview

The problem is - all dates in my example array - `Jul 21, 2017 17:14:00`

But one date is - `Jul 13, 2017 10:39:00`

Now please filter date from - ex. `Jul 12, 2017` to `Jul 14 2017` - output is in 3'rd page. I wan't him to be in first page.
Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: i've look your plunker, and with your query date filter, shows me one and the only 13 date.

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Yeah, but it shows in 3rd page  - I wan't it to show on the top of table

Comment: You have to change `page` to `1` when you apply any filter on table

Comment: as i seen there you are using a filter on repeat, and this would not be supporte d by the pagination

Comment: @AayushiJain, this not solve it, because there is 3 pages and must be 1

Comment: it should not be 3 pages when you filter and it is showing 3 pages as according to it your `dataset` it still has total 13 data values while you are showing only 1 but that's not true

Comment: AS i seen you need to create a custom filter, so the work is early done , put your html range yed done an create the tpl http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-custom-template